# How to run visual studio code in linux

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, rpm

I am new to Linux OS, I downloaded rpm package from of visual studio code from Microsoft official website.This is the machine

```
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
```

I ran the command

```
rpm -qpi code-1.40.2-1574694258.el7.x86_64.rpm

Output of the command

Name        : code
Version     : 1.40.2
Release     : 1574694258.el7
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: (not installed)
Group       : Development/Tools
Size        : 235084185
License     : Multiple, see https://code.visualstudio.com/license
Signature   : (none)
Source RPM  : code-1.40.2-1574694258.el7.src.rpm
Build Date  : Mon 25 Nov 2019 10:04:31 AM EST
Build Host  : 2114565cfb42
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : Visual Studio Code Team <vscode-linux@microsoft.com>
Vendor      : Microsoft Corporation
URL         : https://code.visualstudio.com/
Summary     : Code editing. Redefined.
Description :
Visual Studio Code is a new choice of tool that combines the simplicity of a code editor with what developers need for the core edit-build-debug cycle. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux for installation instructions and FAQ.
```

Now I want to run the visual studio code as I run in windows machine. How do I achieve this?

Note I have only ssh connection to the linux machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should start by installing the package. You only just **queried** the package, to install it, you must (as super user) run:

```
rpm --install code-1.40.2-1574694258.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

once that is installed, you'll be able to launch the program by launching the command:

```
code
```

As @Leon.fon noted, if you have only an `ssh` connection, you won't be able to start a GUI, but exporting your display might work:

```
ssh -X ...
```

Comment: Hi  Chris, that is working :),  If rpm is similar to .zip in windows, I must have seen unpacked files in the same directory, but I don't any other files other than rpm

Comment: `rpm` is much more than a zip file; it is a package manager... installing an `rpm` is like installing a `deb` on ubuntu or `msi` on windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run it via ssh, you need some GUI above the Linux shell.
You can use only command line editors such as; "nano", "vim" and etc.

**Edit:**

Alternative You can run VScode on your local machine and connect it via ssh to remote machine.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

Comment: I am using mobaxterm, I can see UI now

Answer (score 0):

VSCode is a gui based tool. If you only have ssh acces you could try to run it via [x11 forwarding](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-enable-x11-forwarding-on-centos-rhel-567/), or setup a [VNC connection](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server) to remote control the other machine. But as Leon.fon mentioned ssh is usually command line based.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a gui based tool via ssh, then you need to pass `-X` (uppercase) argument which enables X11 forwarding,
`ssh -X remoteHostIP`
See following for 
http://man.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh.1